# java scheduleAtFixedRate method arguments mismatch

Tags: java, eclipse, concurrency, timer, scheduler

I am puzzled why eclipse is reporting that my code using `scheduleAtFixedRate` has a compilation error; an arguments mismatch. Below is ascreenshot showing the code and error message.

[image]

Comment: Did you recently change the arguments?  Perhaps Eclipse is just a little out of sync.  Have you tried compiling?

Comment: Have you checked your imports? Are you importing `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit`? (and not another TimeUnit class)

Comment: This is working fine in my eclipse, maybe your missing an import?

Comment: @Less makes a good point, be sure that they are the RIGHT 'Runnable' and 'TimeUnit' classes, not one from a different package

Comment: hi people, it is the right import, all copy from an online tutorial, interesting is the problem solve it self on restart eclipse this Monday morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this.

Remove all the imports from the class and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> so that the imports are added automatically. If your project is such that it has only the default JDK (and no other libraries then the following imports should be added :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
```

Here is a snapshot of what my class looks like :

[image]

Comment: interesting is the problem solve it self on restart eclipse this Monday morning. suspect eclipse out of sych

Answer (score 0):

I have created the same method and used the correct packages, the class is build in Eclipse and no errors

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Example {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static void initialiseIssueTrackingTask(){

        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };
        stpe.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, 1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi likeToCode, sorry award answer the earlier solution, i had the same code as you 2, it just eclipse need a weekend off to be working again.